# there is no "images & links" tab in joomla 3.4 back-end

Tags: joomla, joomla3.4

I updated my `Joomla` website from `1.5.26` to `2.5` and then to `3.4`, now when I try to write new article or edit previous articles there is no "*images & links*" tab.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this;

Go to your back end and under article options > editing layout, make sure you have **images and links** enabled for back-end. Could be as simple as this?

Img below

[image]